# Get specific cookie value in Java

Tags: cookies

I am setting 2 values for different cookies but domain name is same. So now, how do i get specific cookie value ? Like on one page i want only Email and on another page vice verse.

My code is shown as below :

```
CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();
cm.setAcceptCookie(true);
cm.setCookie("http://www.mytestbuddy.com", "Application=" + Course);
cm.setCookie("http://www.mytestbuddy.com", "Email=" + Email);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```